# Quadratic Equation Application

Tags: quadratics

Textbook exercise I get stuck

"Amy is going to hold a concert at a stadium. The stadium can accommodate 12 000 people.  If the price for each ticket is \$160, all the tickets will be sold.  For every increase of \$1 in the ticket price, the number of tickets sold will decrease by 50.   Let \$p be the price of each ticket and q be the number if tickets sold

(a) express $q$ in terms of $p$, where $p \geq 160$."

Please help!

Comment: How many tickets are sold if the price is $161?

Comment: It will be 11950 tickets

Comment: Would that be a arithmetic sequence relations?

Comment: $q$ will be a linear function of $p$. You're given one $(p,q)$ pair; you just told me another. So can you find $q$ in general now?

Comment: Sorry I am stuck, I don't know how to continue

Comment: '(b) Find the price of each ticket in order to get the maximum income'
That is the part (b) of the question

Comment: Do you understand why $q$ is a linear function of $p$? If so, you know $q(160)=12000$ and $q(161)=11950$, so you should be able to compute $q(p)$ in general.

Comment: Can you help by giving me the solution?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The starting number of tickets sold is $12000\,\text{tickets}$. For each dollar above $160\,\$$, 50 fewer tickets are sold. The number of dollars above $160\,\$$ is
\begin{equation}
p-160\,\$\;.
\end{equation}
The number of tickets sold is therefore
\begin{equation}
q = 12000\,\text{tickets} - \left(50\,\frac{\text{tickets}}{\$}\right)(p - 160\,\$)\;.
\end{equation}

Make sure you understand every part of the previous expression before moving on to part (b).

For part (b), you must use the total revenue from ticket sales:
\begin{align}
\text{Total revenue} &= \text{tickets sold}\times\text{price of tickets}\\
&=q\times p\\
&=\left(12000\,\text{tickets} - \left(50\,\frac{\text{tickets}}{\$}\right)(p - 160\,\$)\right)p\\
&\vdots
\end{align}
Now you can find the vertex or max point of the quadratic function.

Comment: THANKS!!  But how do I form a quadratic equation?

Comment: I answered the question asked. One question, one answer. Ask another question, get another answer. I will add a small part to my answer.